# Python regex for something *not* in a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {"word1":0, "word2":0}
```

For this regex I need to verify that a word in the string **isn't** a key in that dictionary.

Is it possible to set a variable to anything **not** in a dictionary, for the purposes of a regex?

Comment: "a word in the string"?? what string?  why can't you just make a regexp by joining the keys of dict and then try and match on that.  If the match works then your condition fails??  Am I missing some implication in your question?

Comment: No, you have to convert the keys into something that can be consumed by regex tool, or just check one by one, or you can split the string into words and check one by one against dict

Comment: Please define "word".

Comment: What can we assume about the words (keys) in the dict? Can they contain spaces? Can they contain punctuations (e.g. `'`, `-`)? Lots of funny and unexpected thing can happen.

Comment: All the words everywhere are alphanumeric, in this case.  Both the keys in the dictionary, and all the words in the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> d = {"foo":0, "spam":0}
>>> test = "This is a string with many words, including foo and bar"
>>> any(word in d for word in test.split())
True
```

If punctuation is a problem (for example, `"This is foo."` would not find `foo` with this approach), and since you said all your words are alphanumeric, you could also use

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "This is foo."
>>> any(word in d for word in re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9]+", test))
```

Comment: There might be problem with punctuation, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You're right, we should have a definition of what a "word" is in this context. Asking the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about regex in this case:

```
 test = "word1 word2 word3"     # your string
 words = test.split(' ')        # words in your string
 dict = {"word1":0, "word2":0}  # your dict     
 for word in words:
     if word in dict:
         print word, "is a key in dict"
     else:
         print word, "isn't a key in dict"
```

Comment: You need to split the string into words, though. Nothing says that the string contain only 1 word

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, it is not a reserved word, so there's nothing wrong with that. I just followed the example in question. Though of course it is better to avoid such situations.

Comment: There's something wrong with that alright. It may work in this example, but fifty lines down in the code, when trying to call `dict(someiterator)`, you get a `TypeError` and will find it hard to figure out why it isn't working...

Comment: Usually "fifty lines down in the code" I have new function and new scope of variables. :) But, as I said above, in general you are right and beginners should avoid such situations.